# Hubot Slack Integration with SSL

Tags: ssl-certificate, slack, hubot

I am trying to connect Slack over a corporate network using a proxy and it gets blocked on the SSL interception. It gets stuck at:

```
DEBUG slack rtm start with options: {}
```

How to make it go through SSL interception? Is there a way to make Hubot trust SSL certificate?

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you can skip the SSL by setting the environment variable called NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED as zero. This will skip the SSL. eg - for windows execute the following in your command prompt:

```
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

Then run your process as usual

Comment: Thanks Susmita, that worked for now but isn't there a way to make hubot trust CA certificate and go through SSL?

Comment: I am not sure, but you can try setting these environment variables in stead of the one I mentioned in my answer if you want hubot to pass through SSL only:       `HUBOT_SLACK_RTM_START_OPTS='{"token":"<your_slack_token>"}'` 
and `HUBOT_SLACK_RTM_CLIENT_OPTS='{"useRtmConnect": "true"}'`         Hope this helps :)

Comment: Nops setting these environment variables didn't work. :(